# How to add an animated glint running through the edge of my alphabet?

Tags: animation, blender-internal-render-engine, shaders, lighting

I want to show an animated glint/shine running through the edge of my 3-D alphabet. I basically want the **animated shine** to **trace** over the edges of the alphabet once. Basically this but running over the edges of the alphabet.

[image: basically this but running over the edges of the alphabet]
I'm working in blender render.

Comment: Are you using Blender Internal Renderer or Cycles.

Comment: I'm using the blender internal renderer.

Comment: You know what you want, we don't. Tale a step back and consider what terms  like "animated shine" and "edge of alphabet"  would mean to you if you weren't asking the question.   If the answer below is not what you are after; a comment as to why sheds light.   If you can find / create an image or link to something similar that sheds light...  My guess is that you want something like a fuse wire burning around the path of the letter edges??  Yeah I voted to close, just as happy to vote to re-open if you shed some light.

Comment: I'm so sorry I couldn't communicate this effectively.

Answer (score 6):

Animate a lamp which creates a highlight on the text (as the specular component of the text's material).

1. Add a lamp (point light), and [uncheck Diffuse](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/lighting/lights/lamp_panel.html#influence), since we only need the specular reflection as a concentrated highlight.
2. In the viewport, choose GLSL [shading](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/properties/shading.html#shading-panel) (instead of multitextured) in [textured mode](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/properties/shading.html#viewport-shading) to preview the shading.
3. Adjust the text's material's specular [hardness](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/materials/properties/specular_shaders.html#options) and intensity as needed.
4. Position the lamp while looking through the camera at its start position and set a location [keyframe](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/editing.html?highlight=keyframe#keyframing). Repeat with the end position.

[image: Glossy only lamp creating specular highlight]

To make the specular highlight only appear at the edges position the lamp directly underneath/beside the text and give it some depth.

[image]

If you want to create a photographic glow on the highlight, do it in the compositor. After rendering (<kbd>F12</kbd>) enable the compositor nodes. Adding a glare node or screening the blurred highlights will produce an effect of light dispersion across highlighted areas.

[image]